# Issues to split the string in Python

Tags: python, string

I would like to split the searched string into string so that I can search that string in a file and get output.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('t2.txt')
for line in f:
    if '2613'in line:
        words = line.split("/dev")
        print words
```

output of this script is:

`['', '/dm-40\t\t\t3402613000\n']`

I'd like to get `dm-40` from this list and then search it again a file.

Comment: what abount `line.split()` without argument?

Comment: I tried that too at first place. Getting below output

['/dev/dm-40', '3402613000']
now list dont have split inbuilt module to do that

Comment: can you show several lines in the file and what does the result have to be for each of them?

Comment: /dev/dm-17                      33554880
/dev/dm-18                      33554880
/dev/dm-19                      2097600
/dev/dm-20                      67109760
/dev/dm-21                      33554880
/dev/dm-22                      26214720
/dev/dm-23                      67109760
/dev/dm-24                      26214720
/dev/dm-25                      67109760

----- then these devices are mapped with asm devices--------
e.g.

asmzwap01rdo001 dm-133
mpathak dm-82
mpathdz dm-27
asmdwfp01dbf006 dm-199
mpathfw dm-194

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('t2.txt')
for line in f:
    if '2613'in line:
        words = line.split()[0].replace('/dev/', '')
        print words
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. I have figure it out that how I can search dm-40 again in file to get asm device name associated with dm device....

Answer (score 0):

```
words[1].split('\t')[0].replace('/', '', 1)
```